# Header should hide if no user logged-in in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, header, show-hide

My requirement is to hide an Header if no user logged-in in angular 4 application.

I'm trying to implement it in app.component.html and app.component.ts

### app.component.html

```
<app-header *ngIf="isUserLoggedIn"></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from './services/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  public isUserLoggedIn: boolean;

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.isUserLoggedIn = this.authService.isUserLoggedIn(); // returns true if user logged-in otherwise returns false
      console.log(this.isUserLoggedIn);
  }

}
```

above code is working only if page get refreshed and not working whenever url path changed without refresh. Any thoughts/alternate-ideas please?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48098212/1009922) should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`ngOnInit`** gets called only once during the component gets initialized so it works when you refresh the page.

Inorder to make it work  , make a function and return it inside

```
 isLoggedIn(): boolean {
     return this.authService.isUserLoggedIn();
 }
```

and HTML

```
<app-header *ngIf="isLoggedIn()"></app-header>
```

Comment: Using a function in template is not a "good idea", it will be called on every digest cycle because of the data binding. 
You do not want a function to work millions of times for nothing.
Properties should be used for template date bindings, you can set a boolean property by listening an event.